# I don't know how to register my website with facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

My website developer is making me a FAcebook Login button, but he says he needs an application ID and appliecation secret to proceed.

I think I have to register my website with facebook to get the ID, but I cannot work out how to do this.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Create an app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

You'll get given an application ID and secret when you create your app

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an app called "Developer". It will let you setup everything. Just go to apps, and search for developer. It has the Facebook icon.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need for first to create an application here : https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Read this article : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/
   Note : Get your application id from facebook developers(first step)

Answer (score 0):

do a search on facebook's site for app id, or use the link:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/